# spark structured streaming sql window in eventTime

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, bigdata, spark-streaming

How would be the equivalent String SQL query for this very same query:

```scala
val streamingWindowDF = 
  streamingInputDF
    .groupBy(
      $"sessiondId",
      window($"time", "10 seconds","2 seconds"))
```

I would like to do the same but with SQL string something like:

```
val result = spark.sql(".....")
```

What I want to do is a sliding window.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window` is a [valid SQL function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#window) and can be used as such, i.e.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM df
GROUP BY  window(time, '10 seconds', '2 seconds')
```

or in plain  `SELECT`

```
SELECT *, window(time, '10 seconds', '2 seconds') AS w
FROM df
```

Comment: Didn't know `window` was an standard sql function. thx that's was I was looking for.